# How to Update Component State in Each of Mapped Components When One Changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, react-component, react-state-management

I am making a basic app in which images are rendered to the screen. The objective is to not click the same image more than once. I'm using parent state in App comp to count the score (number of first time clicks) and local component state in Image component to see if the image has been clicked already.
App Component is such:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { score: 0 };
  array = [1, 2, 3]

  handleScoreIncrement = (e) => {
    this.setState({ score: this.state.score + 1 })
    console.log(this.state.score)
  }

  handleRestart = () => {
    this.setState({ score: 0 })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Header
          score={this.state.score} />
        {this.array.map((cv, i, arr) => {
          return (
            <div key={cv}>
              <Image
                score={this.state.score}
                increaseScore={this.handleScoreIncrement}
                restart={this.handleRestart}
              />
            </div>
          )
        })
        }

      </div>
    )

  }
};


export default App;
```

I passed the callbacks in the App component as props to the image component to change the state as you can see below. Just stay with me.
Image Component:

```
class Image extends React.Component {

  state = {
    clickedAlready: false,
    score: this.props.score
  }


  handleRestart = () => {
    this.props.restart();
    if (this.props.score === 0) {
      this.setState({ clickedAlready: false })
    }
  }


  handleClickEvent = (e) => {
    if (this.state.clickedAlready) {
      alert('Clicked Already')
      this.handleRestart()
      this.setState({ clickedAlready: false })
    } else {
      this.props.increaseScore();
      this.setState({ clickedAlready: true })
    }
    console.log(this.state.score)
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ border: '1px solid red', marginTop: 5 }}
        onClick={this.handleClickEvent}>Image Would Go Here
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Image;
```

NOW FOR THE PROBLEM: The problem I have is that each time I click an image, it increments correctly, but once I've pressed the same image twice, to reset the game and start over, only THAT specific image changes it's state back to {clickedAlready: false} (so as to restart the game) while the rest still say they have been clicked. It is impossible for me to restart the game if, on reset, all components other than the double-clicked one retain their previous state.
I expected that my event handler in my Image component would reset the state of both the Image comp and App component, thus re-rendering both components, but maybe I am missing something. Please HELP

Essentially, I want, when one Image component has been double-clicked, for all Image components to re-set their state to {clickedAlready: false}.

Comment: The children `Image` components don't react to updates to the `score` prop that is passed. Also, duplicating `score` props into local state is an anti-pattern in React, you want a single source of truth. Since the children are already using a callback to update state in the parent then they should just respond to updates to that state. I'll see if I can create a demonstration when I have a moment.

Comment: I see what you mean -- in the Image component. I meant to remove that redundancy as the code works fine without the score prop in the Image component. Just want to be able to reset all 'twin' Image states (so to say) onClick of an Image comp with {clickedAlready: true} state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main things to update:

Image

1. Use `componentDidUpdate` to reset the `clickedAlready` state when the `score` prop value is updated to `0`. This allows all `Image` components to "reset" when the `score` state is reset in the parent component.

   ```
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
     if (prevProps.score !== this.props.score && this.props.score === 0) {
       this.setState({ clickedAlready: false });
     }
   }
   ```
2. Update `handleClickEvent` to check the `clickedAlready` state to either callback to reset the game or bump the score and update the clicked status.

   ```
   handleClickEvent = (e) => {
     const { clickedAlready } = this.state;
     const { increaseScore, restart } = this.props;
     if (clickedAlready) {
       alert("Clicked Already");
       restart();
     } else {
       increaseScore();
       this.setState({ clickedAlready: true });
     }
   };
   ```

[image: Edit how-to-update-component-state-in-each-of-mapped-components-when-one-changes]

Full code in sandbox demo

```
const Header = ({ score }) => <h1>Score: {score}</h1>;

class Image extends React.Component {
  state = {
    clickedAlready: false
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.score !== this.props.score && this.props.score === 0) {
      this.setState({ clickedAlready: false });
    }
  }

  handleClickEvent = (e) => {
    const { clickedAlready } = this.state;
    const { increaseScore, restart } = this.props;
    if (clickedAlready) {
      alert("Clicked Already");
      restart();
    } else {
      increaseScore();
      this.setState({ clickedAlready: true });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { clickedAlready } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        style={{ border: "1px solid red", marginTop: 5 }}
        onClick={this.handleClickEvent}
      >
        Image Would Go Here {clickedAlready && " - clicked"}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { score: 0 };
  array = [1, 2, 3];

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { score } = this.state;
    console.log(score);
    if (score === this.array.length) {
      alert("Won");
      this.handleRestart();
    }
  }

  handleScoreIncrement = (e) => {
    this.setState({ score: this.state.score + 1 });
  };

  handleRestart = () => {
    this.setState({ score: 0 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header score={this.state.score} />
        {this.array.map((cv, i, arr) => {
          return (
            <div key={cv}>
              <Image
                score={this.state.score}
                increaseScore={this.handleScoreIncrement}
                restart={this.handleRestart}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```